# Why doesn't my counter value ever reach more than 1?

Tags: jquery, ajax, search

I am trying to use count in my jquery search to find the total amount of matches found in total when i get results from  json file after entering a name into a search bar. At the moment I am only getting 1 Matches shown after every individual result instead of the total number of matches in the search. Is there something I am missing here? Thanks

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        $('#result').html('');
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        $.getJSON('address.json', function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                var count = 0;

                if (value.name.search(expression) != -1) {
                    count++;
                    $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item">' 
                        + value.name + '</li>');
                    $('#result').append(count + 'Matches Shown');

                }

                if (searchField == "") {
                    $('#result').html(""); // this clears the SearchBar
                    return; // this makes the bar return to it's original state
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting `count` on each iteration. Define it outside your each function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').keyup(function() {
        $('#result').html('');
        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        var count = 0;

        $.getJSON('address.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                if (value.name.search(expression) != -1) {
                    count++;
                    ...
```